# google map two markers on one map

Tags: php, google-maps

Hey. I'mm trying to put two points on a single map with same div id..
but it doesn't work..
code:

for 1st,

```
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?=$lat;?>,<?=$lng;?>), 6);

  var point = new GLatLng(<?=$lat;?>,<?=$lng;?>);
  var marker = createMarker(point,'Welcome:<b></b><br>Second Info Window with an image<br><img src="http://localhost/gps/user_photo/" width=80 height=80>')
  map.addOverlay(marker);


  function createMarker(point,html) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        });
        return marker;
      }
```

for 2nd,

```
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map-canvas"));
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(<?=$mylat;?>,<?=$mylng;?>), 6);

  var point1 = new GLatLng(<?=$mylat;?>,<?=$mylng;?>);
  var marker = createMarker1(point1,'Welcome:<b></b><br>Second Info Window with an image<br><img src="http://localhost/gps/user_photo/" width=80 height=80>')
  map.addOverlay(marker);


  function createMarker1(point,html) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        });
        return marker;
      }
```

why two points not shown in one map?????
and it will seen in two different maps...

Comment: are they two different lat lng points? why not using V3 google map? Why both markers share one id? Id's are unique

Comment: Aren't you creating two different maps?

Comment: no i want that on one map with this code soo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  //set up map as before

  var point0 = new GLatLng(<?=$mylat0;?>,<?=$mylng0;?>);
  var point1 = new GLatLng(<?=$mylat1;?>,<?=$mylng1;?>);
  var marker0 = createMarker(point0,'Welcome:<b></b><br>First Info Window etc);
  var marker1 = createMarker(point1,'Welcome:<b></b><br>Second Info Window etc);
  map.addOverlay(marker);

// only declare this once
  function createMarker(point,html) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        });
        return marker;
      }
```

This is one way of doing it just to get it working for you, but essentially the js points and markers should be arrays which you loop through - ditto probably the $mylat and $mylong vars in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood - you want to add two points on one map, on the one page.
If so - you don't need to initialize Gmap twice, just do something like this:
http://pastebin.com/BtvdfaiP

Comment: but it steel working on this code:var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
         map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$mylat;?>, <?=$mylng;?>),
            zoom: 13,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         });
                  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

Comment: you are right but with different codes i got two different points(lat,lng) so

Comment: i'm not sure that i understand your goal correctly. Can u plz describe it more clear?